# Jinja2: Render template inheritance?

Tags: python, extend, jinja2

I'd like to render a fused Jinja2 and Markdown page using a template, which looks like so:

```
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

# {{ title[0] }}
# {{ title[1] }}

## Introduction
```

I can get that above code to generate HTML fine, but as I am using this script for a custom authoring application, I'd like to be able to define master templates for each type of entry.

When I try to render the above page by extending a master template, `template.html`:

```
{% extends 'template.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

# {{ title[0] }}
# {{ title[1] }}

## Introduction
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compiler.py", line 55, in <module>
    template = Template(text).render(parser.vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 891, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified
```

You can see that the problematic line is `template = Template(text).render(parser.vars)`.

Is there any way that I can render the above template code and be able to extend `template.html`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Jinja's renderer needs to know how to load `template.html`, so you need to give the `Environment` a template loader instance.

For example, assuming the files `page.html` and `template.html` are in the current directory:

```
from jinja import FileSystemLoader
from jinja.environment import Environment

env = Environment()
env.loader = FileSystemLoader('.')
tmpl = env.get_template('page.html')
print tmpl.render(parser.vars)
```

---

**Updated** - You can create a custom template loader, or use one of the existing classes defined in [jinja2.loaders](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/loaders.py).  For example, the `DictLoader` would look up `template.html` in a `dict()` instance and treat the value as the template data. It should be straightforward to load your templates from just about anywhere (e.g. memcache, mysql, redis, a Python object, etc).

Example of using `DictLoader`:

```
pages = ('template.html', 'page.html')
templates = dict((name, open(name, 'rb').read()) for name in pages)
env.loader = DictLoader(templates)
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Am I forced to save my template to a text file, or can `get_template` work with a string input? I'll go read the documentation again...

Comment: You're welcome! I updated my answer with a bit of detail on Jinja's template loaders.

Comment: I'm using `DictLoader`, but the traceback is completely weird: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: (my template HTML here)`. I define the `dict` normally, `{'templates/article.html': '...', ...}`, but it is only read when I reverse it. What...?

Comment: Hmm, `DictLoader` works for me (I changed my example locally and it works).  Are you sure the paths you're using are correct, e.g. does the path used in `{% extends "name.html" %}` exactly match a dictionary key?

Comment: Facepalm moment. Turns out I was rendering the internal variable `template`, which was my actual template's code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean `from jinja*2*...`?